# Layout of an edmx diagram in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, edmx

I have an entity framework diagram that has been generated from my database and updated several times. Upon adding new tables the placement of them seems to be a bit random and it has led to a pretty messy picture (example below). Is there a way of getting it to auto-rearrange them?

I'm more interested in finding out how it decides where to place a new table, if anyone happens to know...? This is more curiosity than an actual problem I suppose.

[image: Messy edmx screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This may be unrelated, but to find a certain table, I have found myself opening the edmx.diagram file with a text editor and searched for the table.

When I have found it, I have modified the  nodes and set PointX="0" and PointY="0".

Then I had opened the diagram again in visual studio, having the table in question in the topleft corner.

Comment: A cunning plan, but what I really wanted to know was how VS decides the PointX and PointY of a newly added table. Useful info though!

Comment: I got the impression that newly added tables are placed mainly below other tables, requires further investigation however

Answer (score 1):

Try moving some related tables to a new diagram by right-clicking on the table and selecting "move to another diagram". thereafter right-click in a blank space, diagram, layout diagram to rearrange the tables.